# Merging multiple data.tables

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I am aware that one can merge (join) two `data.table` with the `merge` function or the `[.data.table` function.  However, if I have say 10, `data.table`s and want to use `do.call` to merge them all together, is there a function that would do this? Currently I resort to `do.call(cbind, ...)` which works for only very special cases.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe (untested) :

```
Reduce(merge,list(DT1,DT2,DT3,...))
```

Comment: The reduce solution works nice, but I don't know how to specify all=TRUE. Any idea?

Comment: @sdaza Hm good question. All I can think currently is to create a wrapper like `mymerge = function(x,y) merge.data.table(x,y,all=TRUE)` and pass that wrapper to `Reduce` instead, i.e. `Reduce(mymerge,list(DT1,DT2,DT3,...))`.

Comment: [the all = T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) worked for me in data.table.

Comment: If your `data.table`s are unkeyed, the wrapper should look like `function(x, y) x[y, on = "merge_column_name"]`

Answer (score 42):

To flesh out the solution suggested by @Henk in comments, here is how to use this to select the `all = TRUE` option in a concise formulation:

```
MergedDT = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), List_of_DTs)
```

Comment: This method works well, but I also like to add:  ```R Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE, sort=FALSE), .)``` because allowing sort to be the default value of TRUE will rekey to the shared key columns. This can break future merges, if for example you've created a list of data.tables with the appropriate keys and you want to merge them all on any shared keys.

Answer (score 8):

The latest version of data.table (1.10.5) has an easy syntax for table join, which can also be chained.

```
 set(DT1, key)
 set(DT2, key) 
  ...
 set(DT10, key)

 DT_cmb <- DT1[DT2,][DT3,]...[DT10,]
```

Comment: This solution seems good, but it can be exhaustive if you have several `data.table`'s. Probably, there is an easy (and more generic) way to do it using `lapply` and `ls(pattern = '^DT')` instead.

Comment: @lcgodoy Yeah, I like to use `lapply()` along with `setkeyv( )` in these situations, especially since I'll already want the `data.table`s in a list to use my preferred [merge syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39561045/3541976)

Comment: this syntax is there for ages, and chaining works for ages as well, the problem is that it does not scale, as you might have a list of data.table that varies in quantity

Answer (score 0):

To fresh answer from Michael Ohlrogge, here I create a function to do this task. You can inherit more arguments from `merge.data.table()`

```r
mergeDTs <- function(dt_list, by = NULL, sort = FALSE) {
  Reduce(
    function(...) {
      merge(..., by = by, all = TRUE, sort = sort)
    }, dt_list)
}
```