# How to merge a list of data.tables without getting splitted columns?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I'm about to merge large data sets. That's why I try out data.table and am thrilled by its speed.

```
# base R
system.time(
  M1 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), L)
  )
# user  system elapsed 
# 5.05    0.00    5.20 

# data.table    
library(data.table)
L.dt <- lapply(L, function(x) setkeyv(data.table(x), c("sid", "id")))
system.time(
  M2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), L.dt)
  )
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.12    0.00    0.12
```

Both approaches yield the same values, however there are some columns that are split with data.table.

*base R:*

```
set.seed(1)
car::some(M1, 5)
#        sid    id         V3        V4          a         b
# 60504    1 60504 -0.6964804 -1.210195         NA        NA
# 79653    1 79653 -2.5287163 -1.087546         NA        NA
# 111637   2 11637  0.7104236        NA -1.7377657        NA
# 171855   2 71855  0.2023342        NA -0.6334279        NA
# 272460   3 72460 -0.5098994        NA         NA 0.2738896
```

*data.table:*

```
set.seed(1)
car::some(M2, 5)
#    sid    id       V3.x        V4      V3.y          a         V3         b
# 1:   1 60504 -0.6964804 -1.210195        NA         NA         NA        NA
# 2:   1 79653 -2.5287163 -1.087546        NA         NA         NA        NA
# 3:   2 11637         NA        NA 0.7104236 -1.7377657         NA        NA
# 4:   2 71855         NA        NA 0.2023342 -0.6334279         NA        NA
# 5:   3 72460         NA        NA        NA         NA -0.5098994 0.2738896
```

Did I miss something? Or is there an easy way to solve this, i.e. get the split columns combined? (I don't want to use any other packages.)

***Data***

```
fun <- function(x){
  set.seed(x)
  data.frame(cbind(sid=x, id=1:1e5, matrix(rnorm(1e5*2), 1e5)))
}
tmp <- lapply(1:3, fun)
df1 <- tmp[[1]]
df2 <- tmp[[2]]
df3 <- tmp[[3]]
rm(tmp)
names(df2)[4] <- c("a")
names(df3)[4] <- c("b")
L <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

*Related:* [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097519/6574038), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274291/6574038)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `by` argument in `base::merge` defaults to `intersect(names(x), names(y))` where `x` and `y` are the 2 tables to be merged. Hence, `base::merge` also uses `V3` as the merging key.

The `by` argument in `data.table::merge` defaults to the shared key columns between the two tables (i.e. `sid` and `id` in this case). And since the tables have columns named `V3`, suffixes are appended to the new columns.

So if your intention is to merge by all common columns, you can identify the common columns, set keys then merge:

```
commcols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(L, names))
L.dt <- lapply(L, function(x) setkeyv(data.table(x), commcols))
M2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), L.dt)
```

Comment: Ok, in my real data, as you can imagine, there are hundreds of `V3`s, which is actually the point.

Comment: you can specify your `by` columns if you really want to merge by V3 as well. or `L.dt <- lapply(L, function(x) setkeyv(data.table(x), c("sid", "id", "V3")))` if this is really what you intended and what you did with `base::merge`

Comment: And this then continues with the `a`s and `b`s and `c`s and ... from the `dt`s to merge.

Comment: just identify the common columns using `by=Reduce(intersect, lapply(L.dt, names))`

Comment: I have a follow-up issue up with the real data, though. Error message `x has some duplicated column name(s)` citing 118 names, data has 431 names. Thought it was related to `intersect` and tried `union` but didn't help. Could you clarify that here, or shall I rather ask another question?

Comment: which line is causing the error? `commcols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(L, names))`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184118/discussion-between-jay-sf-and-chinsoon12).